# How do I set up pricing for wholesale and retail and there quantity on my web site in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

This is what I am trying to do. 
I have store a retail.com 
and wholesale.com

but I have different pricing for each one and I want the inventory to all come out of the same spot I dont want to have to check 2 spots to track my inventory.

also on the retail site items are sold as one so when some places 1 in the quantity box it means one 
but on the whole sale site when you put 1 in the quantity box it mean a case like 12 or 24

and on the pricing side 
the wholesale will be sold as a box which might cost 20.00 
and on the retail side the same item may cost 2.99

how can I set this up in my site.

Comment: i am using magento 1.9.1

Comment: SO is not a product tech support site - it is designed to help solve programming problems.  So, in short, if there is no source code to debug, this is not the correct place for your question.